# Cucumber bdd how to input random data

Tags: cucumber-java

I have a data input scenario like this.

I wanted to input sub sequent item
Item 2 and verify list has

```
Item 2
Item 1
```

Till......x20 items.

What is the b3st way to do it instead if copy paste the same scenario over and over?

```
  Scenario: Adding item
    Given i have a new list
    When I add "item 1"
    Then item list has:
      | item 1 |
```